# Flutter: Image height dynamic will be changed according to text height increase and decrease

Tags: image, flutter, dart, text, gridview

i set an image on top and multiple line text on bottom in GridView-builder index. next i want image height size will be changed dynamically while text line will be changed.
suppose, when bottom  text line will increase then top image height will be deceased in index.

```
 class category_route extends StatelessWidget {


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {



var sizeDevice = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
final orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;

final double itemHeight = (sizeDevice.height - kToolbarHeight - 24) / 3;
final double itemWidth = sizeDevice.width / 3;



return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(

    backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,

    body: GridView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemCount: categoryTitleArray.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: (orientation == Orientation.portrait) ? 3 : 4,
        crossAxisSpacing: 5,
        mainAxisSpacing: 5,
        childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
      ),


      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new Card(

        child: new GridTile(
          
            child:  Image.asset(categoryImageArray[index],
            ),
            footer: Text("${categoryTitleArray[index]}"),

          ),
        );
      },
    ),


  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using GridTile  Please use this

```
return 
new Card(
  child: new Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Image.network(
          categoryImageArray[index],
        ),
      ),
      Text("${categoryTitleArray[index]}")
    ],
  ),
);
```

I tested this and working perfectly.  Hope I answer the question.